# I am trying to generate short story using openai in nodejs but its throw error

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

i am tyring to generate a short story with the help of openai api in nodejs but i am getting this error message "400 We could not parse the JSON body of your request. (HINT: This likely means
you aren't using your HTTP library correctly. The OpenAI API expects a JSON
payload, but what was sent was not valid JSON. If you have trouble figuring out
how to fix this, please contact us through our help center at help.openai.com.)" while doing a post request here's my code.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
require("dotenv").config();
const OpenAIApi = require("openai");
const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;
const openai = new OpenAIApi({ key: apiKey });
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await openai.completions.create("text-davinci-001", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      prompt: req.body.prompt,
      max_tokens: 100, // Adjust the maximum length of the generated story as needed
      temperature: 0.7, // Adjust the temperature to control randomness
    });

    console.log(response.choices[0].text);
    return res.send(response.choices[0].text);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating short story:", error);
    return res.send(error.message);
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

if there is any mistake in my code then please help me.